# Domain Delegation isn't working

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone

I made the mistake of registering a domain with Arvixe. The domain name is `artofshell.com`, and I'm trying to delegate this domain over to Microsoft Azure's DNS service.

1. I created a DNS Zone in Azure, and set up several record sets
2. I verified, using PowerShell's `Resolve-DnsName` command, that the DNS servers are responding properly
3. I set up four (NS) records on Arvixe to point to the Azure DNS servers
4. DNS resolution against the records in Azure DNS fails

When I query for SOA records, I am seeing `ns1.crowfoot.arvixe.com` instead of the Azure DNS servers. Is that correct, or is something misconfigured on the Arvixe side? Whatever the case, they aren't routing traffic correctly.

## Screenshot: NS Records pointing to Azure DNS

[image: Arvixe DNS NS Records]

## Screenshot: Azure DNS Zone

[image: Azure DNS Zone]

## Screenshot: SOA Record for domain

[image: Arvixe SOA Record]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your domain is configured to use those servers at the registrar level. You will need to modify the registrar settings to match your NS record changes in the zone file.

The below answer comes from the TLD nameservers for `.com`, which is what matters most here.

```
artofshell.com.         172800  IN      NS      ns1.crowfoot.arvixe.com.
artofshell.com.         172800  IN      NS      ns2.crowfoot.arvixe.com.
CK0POJMG874LJREF7EFN8430QVIT8BSM.com. 86400 IN NSEC3 1 1 0 - CK0Q1GIN43N1ARRC9OSM6QPQR81H5M9A NS SOA RRSIG DNSKEY NSEC3PARAM
CK0POJMG874LJREF7EFN8430QVIT8BSM.com. 86400 IN RRSIG NSEC3 8 2 86400 20160412045951 20160405034951 28259 com. tWAc1PvnwRb/p7yhrRofU7WueUorZbqRFbWUeO/QSoWrWsh53IV7BlVc tRBKLi85BdWxR7Xs21n/tlrhoheu8U7QtULUq5vhS6h4iDBISrjasCrG FUQ0J7M+PjCKj1cwFvFuWPpr517pQSMGyYxn1eIiuVcraxVDuq8a0X9x Nss=
GDV43SDF972ESHI2CQH6A4Q335OOOUQO.com. 86400 IN NSEC3 1 1 0 - GDV7BD7GQPNAJSG70HH14BOP2JFTR5CB NS DS RRSIG
GDV43SDF972ESHI2CQH6A4Q335OOOUQO.com. 86400 IN RRSIG NSEC3 8 2 86400 20160414041818 20160407030818 28259 com. RSRlVzpUpsDwNtiroAIu4eoPZt8dCCy3ZN5aWg5FWc5wGDWYVOd5l2P6 2PZ7wcA2B1Y4vQJpyeAhsKea3l3ve1f5OfXuXJDvipOA5NnAgdvTHtem EkeBYpa1a3QwR2zV4xlQtMduvrwxPuy/+1QjzmLAM2jQZBRRcDsLxnVa iNY=
ns1.crowfoot.arvixe.com. 172800 IN      A       23.91.70.70
ns2.crowfoot.arvixe.com. 172800 IN      A       143.95.251.45
;; Received 612 bytes from 192.55.83.30#53(m.gtld-servers.net) in 224 ms
```

Comment: Thanks -- it turns out that there was a separate management console to edit the domain delegation. They use cPanel to manage hosting accounts, and then use a separate "customer portal" to manage domain delegation.